# Сравнение чисел с плавающей запятой с ограниченной точностью

Tags: числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Нужно сравнить следующие пары чисел с точностью до 4-х значащих цифр.

1. 1134 и 1132
2. 9933 и 9932
3. 11344 и 11342
4. 99343 и 99342.

Соответственно, в первых двух случаях числа получаются неравными, а в последних - равными. Пробовал ввести заранее eps=0.001, и сравнивать его с относительными погрешностями, но не все тесты проходят. Также выяснил, что первая значащая цифра влияет на порядок числа. Как проделать это решение чисто математически, чтобы потом уже написать на любом языке?

Comment: Числа могут быть только целые?

Comment: нет. просто эти примеры были приведены преподавателем

Comment: если разобраться с ними, то с нецелыми по идее проблем не должно быть

Comment: все, что после 4 цифры просто отсекается или округляется по обычным правилам ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так:

1. Ищем максимальное `10^n`, такое, что оно меньше данного числа.
2. Делим найденное число на `1000`.
3. Сравниваем результаты деления чисел на свои `10^n`.

### Примеры на ЯП

C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int get_d(int n){
    return pow(10, int(log10(n)))/1000;
}

bool is_equal(int n1, int n2){
    return n1/get_d(n1) == n2/get_d(n2);
}

int main(){
    int n1, n2;

    n1 = 99344;
    n2 = 99346;

    cout << is_equal(n1, n2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему делим на 1000?

Comment: @АлексейГросс нужно 4 знака точности, а 10^4 = 10000. а мы делим на степень меньше т.к. ищем максимальное меньше. Если бы искали минимальное больше, то делили бы на 10000.
На самом деле можно просто `pow(10, int(log10(n)-3))` написать.

Answer (score 0):

На питоне вообще в строковом виде проще решить:

```
def compare_n(a, b, n):
    return str(a)[:n] == str(b)[:n] 

assert(not compare_n(1134, 1132, 4))
assert(not compare_n(9933, 9932, 4))
assert(compare_n(11344, 11342, 4))
assert(compare_n(99343, 99342, 4))
```

Но можно и математически:

```
import math

def cut_n(x, n):
    ix = int(math.log10(x)) + 1
    return x // math.pow(10, ix - n if n < ix else 0)

def compare_n(a, b, n):
    return cut_n(a, n) == cut_n(b, n)

assert(not compare_n(1134, 1132, 4))
assert(not compare_n(9933, 9932, 4))
assert(compare_n(11344, 11342, 4))
assert(compare_n(99343, 99342, 4))
```

Comment: под математическим решением я подразумевал решение на бумаге

Comment: на маленьких числах алгоритм не работает. к примеру, если взять -1.009e-7 и -1.008e-7

Comment: У вас не получится решить эту задачу, если вы будете использовать числа с плавающей запятой (float, double) - из-за перевода десятичных дробей в двоичные и обратно.
Не все десятичные дроби можно представить в виде конечных двоичных дробей.

Используйте арифметику с фиксированной запятой.

Comment: И как это сделать?

Comment: И еще вопрос: как учесть то, что первая значащая цифра влияет на порядок числа?